# JSON Conversion

Tags: apex, json

I want to convert a JSON to a particular format in apex

**JSON**

```
{
  "customers" : [ {
    "Sales_Force_Customer_ID" : "0012500001xxydWAAQ",
    "FirstName" : "wfwdwe",
    "Surname" : "wedwed",
    "Email" : "wefrerw@gmail.com",
    "Mobile" : "89123677882",
    "CountryOfResidence" : "AF",
    "MaritalStatus" : "Single",
    "CountryOfNationality" : "DZ"
  } ]
}
```

The format to which I want to convert

```
{"customers":"[{\"Sales_Force_Customer_ID\": \"0012500001xxydWAAQ\",\"BirthDate\": \"2000-11-11\",\"Salutation\":\"Mr.\",\"FirstName\": \"Rehan\",\"MiddleName\":\"Kumar\",\"Surname\": \"Singh\",\"Email\": \"abc@gmail.com\",\"Mobile\":\"6455647565\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"CountryOfResidence\":\"UAE\",\"CountryOfNationality\":\"UAE\"}]"}
```

I tried to serialize the JSON, removing \n, but it didn't worked

```
global class CustomertoSOHOIntegration {

  @future(callout = true)
  global static void Customersoho(Set<Id> acclst) {
     
  List<Account> DelAccLst= [select id, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, PersonEmail, PersonMobilePhone, Client_ID__c, Birth_Date__c ,
                            Gender__c ,Store_Name__c ,Salutation,Email_LS__c,Salesforce_Record_Id__c, Country_of_Residence__c , Country_Of_Nationality__c,Marital_Status__c from Account where Id IN:acclst];

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    //request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'mlozLiogk7ltPmhLxz22jxxxxx');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    String endpoint = 'https:/xxxxxxxxxcom/xxx/d90d7025xxx9-4902-adff-d6c52b5f8885/UAT/ODataV4/xxxxx';
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint); 
    req.setTimeout(120000);
      map<String,String> mapOfcountry = new map<String, String>(); 
        Map<String, Country_code__mdt> countryName2 = Country_code__mdt.getAll();
        for(Country_code__mdt  country2 : countryName2.values()){
            
            mapOfcountry.put(country2.Country_Code__c,country2.DeveloperName);
            
        }
     List<Account> accntLst = new List<Account>();
     List<Account> accntLstprimary = new List<Account>();
     List<Account> accntLstJoint = new List<Account>();
     String jsonData = '';
     
     if(!DelAccLst.isEmpty()){
            JSONGenerator jsonGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('customers');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
            for(Account con : DelAccLst){
               
              
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                if(con.Salesforce_Record_Id__c  != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Sales_Force_Customer_ID',con.Salesforce_Record_Id__c); 
                }
                  if(con.Birth_Date__c != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('BirthDate',con.Birth_Date__c); 
                }
                  if(con.Salutation != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Salutation',con.Salutation); 
                }
                 if(con.FirstName != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('FirstName',con.FirstName); 
                }
                 if(con.MiddleName != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('MiddleName',con.MiddleName); 
                }
                 if(con.LastName != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Surname',con.LastName); 
                }
                 if(con.Email_LS__c  != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Email',con.Email_LS__c ); 
                }
                  if(con.PersonMobilePhone != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Mobile',con.PersonMobilePhone); 
                }
                 if(con.Gender__c != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Gender',con.Gender__c); 
                }
                if(con.Country_of_Residence__c != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('CountryOfResidence',mapOfcountry.get(con.Country_of_Residence__c)); 
                }
                 if(con.Marital_Status__c != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('MaritalStatus',con.Marital_Status__c); 
                }
                  if(con.Country_Of_Nationality__c != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('CountryOfNationality',mapOfcountry.get(con.Country_Of_Nationality__c)); 
                }
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
            }
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                
              
               
                
                 jsonData = jsonGen.getAsString();
               
         String source = (String)JSON.serialize(jsonData);
                
                 System.debug('Json Data - ' + jsonData);
             System.debug('Json Data  serialize- ' +  source.replaceAll('\n',''));
                 req.setBody(jsonData);
                 system.debug('CC ID');
                 Http http = new Http();
                 try{
                 HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
                 sYSTEM.debug('RESPONSE ' + response.getBody());
                String jsonString = response.getBody().replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('\r','');    
                 Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());  
                    
                 if (response.getStatusCode() == 200 || response.getStatusCode() == 201) {
                     
                    System.debug('SUCCESS ' + response.getBody());
                  
                 }
                 else {
                    // map_value = (Map < String, Object > ) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                      
                       System.debug('FAILURE ' + response.getBody() + response.getStatus());
                      
                     
                }
              }
                catch(System.CalloutException ex){
                System.debug('Callout error: '+ ex);
                    
            }
            
            
                
              
            }
         
         
            
     
           
        
   
    
      
   
       

  }
    
   
     

}
```

Please help me...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have updated the question..Please check

Comment: Nowhere above do you seem to clearly articulate a problem you are facing. "It did not work" is not specific enough for the community to offer help.

Comment: This is [an X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info). For what reason are you trying to do this? What goal does this help you achieve? Serializing JSON makes little sense _because JSON itself is a serialized format_. Also, JSON doesn't have newlines unless you're _pretty printing_. Also, using `JSONParser` and/or `JSONGenerator` should be a _last resort_ (it's overly verbose and prone to errors). In 99.9% of cases, using `JSON.serialize()` and/or `JSON.deserialize()` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you appear to be aiming to produce has one name "customers" with one value that is a string that in itself is serialised JSON, hence the escaped quotes.

If you really want that you can do it e.g. like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> customers = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
for(Account a : delAccLst) {
    customers.add(new Map<String, Object>{
        'Sales_Force_Customer_ID' => a.Id,
        'FirstName' => a.FirstName,              // ???
        ...
    });
}

Map<String, Object> root = new Map<String, Object>{
    'customers' => JSON.serialize(customers)
};

String jsonString = JSON.serialize(root);
```

Comment: thanks!!..it worked